# C++ Why the compiler failed with the error code C2280 when the deleted function is not used

Tags: c++, move-constructor

I'm trying to understand why the compiler failed with an error code C2280 (attempting to reference a deleted function) when the deleted function is never used.

Here an example of code that fails

```cpp
class A {
public:
    A() { 
        cout << "default" << endl;
    }

    A(A const&) {
        cout << "copy" << endl;
    }

    A(A&&) = delete;

    A create() {
        return A();
    }
};

void main() {
    A a;
    A b(a.create());
}
```

And the same code that I don't understand

```cpp
class A {
public:
    A() { 
        cout << "default" << endl;
    }

    A(A const&) {
        cout << "copy" << endl;
    }

    A(A&&) {
        cout << "move" << endl;
    }

    A create() {
        return A();
    }
};

void main() {
    A a;
    A b(a.create());
}
```

This code compiles but doesn't display "move" on the console.

The result is

```
default
default
```

Comment: Try compiling with `-fno-elide-constructors`.

Comment: @Kerrek Fairly obviously, this is the MS compiler.

Comment: See [Return Value Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#Return_value_optimization) and [Copy/Move elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).  `create()` is being optimized to avoid the move operation, that is why the move constructor is not being called.

Comment: Older versions of standard often allow but do not require the compiler to elide (i.e. not create) temporaries, which means that relevant constructors don't need to be called.   However, before eliding temporaries, the compiler is required to check the code under the assumption that it will not elide temporaries, which means checking that the relevant constructors can be called.

Comment: Unrelated: `void main()` is non-standard. Clearly your compiler is OK with that, but most compilers will report a syntax error and refuse to compile. `int main()` is Standard approved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before C++17 copy elision was an optional optimization, but compiler still have to check that copy/move constructor available. Starting from C++17 your code will compile without error.